# Achieving the correct contrast/gradient with a background image & text

Tags: html, css

I really like the look of crisp background images with a text overlay. However, I always seem to find the text is drowned out by the background image when I do them. So I am always looking for the correct solution or industry standard for using this background -> text technique.

Looking at this image from Adobe, the background image appears darker than the actual image. Using inspect element I cannot see what is causing this- no opacity or gradients. What technique are they using to darken this and what should be used in situations like this?

http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/experience-design.html

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at the CSS of the element and here is your answer:

```
.hero2-fx-frame-2[class*="hero2-theme-1"]::after {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95), transparent 53%), linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95), transparent 53%);
}
```

It's basically a black layer with 53% of opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Use independent divs. Don't nest the text div inside the image div. Then test different gradients on both divs until you get what you are looking for.